# Is there a way to capture the row checkbox change event on AG Grid React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

I'm currently using AG Grid for React in one of my applications. All my rows have checkboxes to indicate further inspection. I want to capture when the checkbox checked state changes. I can use `onRowSelected` event for this but with one caveat, this event fires for both unselected rows and checkboxes. I need something to differentiate between an actual checkbox value/event and a row selection.

I need an event or an atribute/function that only fires/specifies when checkbox is checked/unchecked.

Is this available on Ag-grid React?

Comment: You can select a row by clicking on it or by using checkbox. Do you want to capture only if row selected and do nothing when row unselected?

Comment: hey @AhmetFiratKeler I want to capture when the checkbox in the row changes state.

Comment: You can get its state by diggin through the param object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Okay you want to capture only if the row is selected by a checkbox event.**

Well if you dig through the event parameter of the grid events, you can get lots of details. I like this feature of Ag-Grid.

onRowSelected has a parameter called `source`. We can use it for this purpose.

```
const onRowSelected = useCallback((event) => {
  console.log('onRowSelected event', event);

  if (event.source === 'checkboxSelected')
    window.alert(
      'Node is ' +
        (event.node.isSelected() ? 'selected' : 'deselected') +
        ' by checkbox'
    );
}, []);
```

Here you are, I got a plunker ready for you as a reference: https://plnkr.co/edit/qlZOvGrYmwbszP12?preview

Further reading: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-selection-rowSelected